# How to edit a pre-existing model in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How do you edit a pre-existing model in Gazebo?

I created a very simple model in SDF following a tutorial, and now I'm trying to follow [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=model_editor&cat=model_editor_top) tutorial on how to edit an existing model in the GUI model editor. However, the tutorial's instructions doesn't match Gazebo 4.

I can insert my model onto the stage, but then it says to "Right click on the model you just inserted and select Edit Model", yet the right-click menu shows no such option.

If I click Edit->Model Editor, I get the model editing screen, but it doesn't seem to let me actually edit the model I just inserted. Does model editing not work in Gazebo 4 or am I doing something wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8408/how-to-edit-a-pre-existing-model-in-gazebo/) by [Cerin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1031/cerin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2015-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The tutorial you referenced is for Gazebo versions 6.0+. Gazebo 6 will be released in the end of July 2015.

Until then, the most convenient way to edit an existing model is to make changes directly to the SDF file and insert the model again into the scene to see the changes, as explained in [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=build_robot&cat=build_robot) tutorial.

An alternative is to build Gazebo [from source](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_from_source&cat=install) (with `hg up default`) and use the Model Editor from the tutorial you referenced, but since you'd be using our development branch, be aware that there might be unknown bugs.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2863/shawnysh/) on 2016-10-15**:
I came across the same problem even if my version is 7.4.0, still not working at all, what should I do ? Thanks

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-11-09**:
What options do you see when you right-click the model?

**Comment by [Subodh Malgonde](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6243/subodh-malgonde/) on 2018-08-12**:
I am using Gazebo v9.0.0 and I still don't have an option to edit the model. When I right click on it, I get 3 options copy, paste and delete.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-08-13**:
Strange, maybe the menu is leaking out of the screen? You listed the 3 last options, but there are 5 more above those, one of which is "Edit model"